# AngularFire FirebaseStorage Callback not working from snapshot method

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

There are no errors I just want to check if the call back is working. But it is not.
This is for AngularFireStorage, After I upload an Image, I am planning to get the downloadURL but the problem is, the pipe for observable is not working, I also tried to use { tap } but no luck.

this  is the code

```
    const path = `hospital/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;

const customMetadata = { app : 'PROV-H meta'};

const ref = this.storage.ref(path);

this.task = ref.put(file,{customMetadata});


this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();

this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(()=>{
    console.log("percent finalize");
  })
);
```

This is the logs from the Console.

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1540028075438".
```

zone.js:2969 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prov-h-fae96.appspot.com/o?name=hospital%2F1540028079723_caps.png".

just a bunch of those. No errors.

Is there any alternatives to get the downloadUrl path?

FYI, I can't subscribe to the downloadURL if I can't make the callback work.

```
 this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(()=>{
    console.log("percent finalize"); //THIS IS NOT GETTING CALLED;
  })
);
```

Comment: you need to subscribing like `pipe(finalize(...)).subscribe()` to trigger the lazy process.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
 finalize(()=>{
   console.log("percent finalize");
   })
 );
 this.snapshot.subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```